# Maven multi-module non-resolvable parent

Tags: maven

i'm facing a build error in maven, which i'm unable to explain, my project layout is:

```
root
|--parent
|--project
```

where root (aggregator) and project both use "parent" as their parent.

i used this layout in another project, which maven is able to build.
however, in this project, if i'm trying to build, i get a failure on non-resolvable parent pom:

```
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for maven.test:maven-test-project:9.9.9-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact maven.test:maven-test-parent:pom:9.9.9-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 11, column 10
```

if i remove the parent node from the root (aggregator) pom, maven is able to build the project successfully.

if i use an older version of maven (3.3 instead of 3.6) the project is built successfully as well.

here are the poms for all 3 projects:

**root**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>maven.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-test</artifactId>
    <version>9.9.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>Maven Test</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>maven.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-test-parent</artifactId>
        <version>9.9.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <modules>
        <module>parent</module>
        <module>project</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

**parent**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>maven.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-test-parent</artifactId>
    <version>9.9.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>Maven Parent</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

**project**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> 

    <artifactId>maven-test-project</artifactId>
    <version>9.9.9-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>Maven Project</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>maven.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-test-parent</artifactId>
        <version>9.9.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
</project>
```

Comment: `root` has a module `parent` and uses it as a Parent POM? That sounds strange to me.

Comment: You should follow convention over configuration paradigm and let your parent the parent of the childs and don't use a parent which is a sibling of other childs...

Comment: @khmarbaise - i have usage for this parent in other projects, so i can't have it function as both aggregator and parent.

Comment: Then it does not belong into the directory tree. You should make a separate project of the parent and that's correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

There's a conception issue.

"root" cannot be at the same time a parent **and** child of the same Maven module "parent".

Comment: it isn't the parent, it's only an aggregator. the parent is the "parent" project.
note that this setup works with older maven version.

Comment: It might work technically, but the concept is not really Maven-like. Things like this are always on the brink of breaking.